# ssh tunnel for socks proxying

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks

I'm scratching my head over this; I've spent many hours reading, please help.

Simplifying, I have one site mydomain.com that has one gateway router (router-1 192.168.1.1), one router configured as switch (192.168.1.184) and AP running OpenWrt with OpenSSH package, as well as a number of machines.

On router-1 I open port 59409 and forward it to switch 192.168.1.184:22

Then I have my macOS laptop in another network; I've setup up the rsa keys so when I issue:

```
$ ssh root@mydomain.com -p 59409
```

I get a command line of the switch; so, the authentication works, all is well for a connection.

Then I issue the command to establish a tunnel to use the switch as a proxy to the intranet inside mydomain.com:

```
$ ssh -N -v -4 -g -D 127.0.0.1:1080 -p 59409 -l root mydomain.com
```

I get, on other terminal of the laptop:

```
me@mylaptop ~ $ netstat -an | grep 1080
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.1080         *.*                    LISTEN     
me@mylaptop ~ $ netstat -an | grep 59409
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.147.59145    99.99.99.99.59409     ESTABLISHED # public IP obfuscated
```

I would then expect nmap to scan the intranet in mydomain.com:

```
$ sudo nmap -sS -O -v3 -d9 --proxies socks4://127.0.0.1:1080 192.168.1.0/24
```

But instead it scans the network where my laptop is; the proxying is not being done.

I also tried:

```
$ sudo proxychains4 nmap -sS -O -v3 -d9 192.168.1.0/24
```

with /etc/proxychains.conf:

```
...
[ProxyList]
socks5  127.0.0.1 1080
```

socks4 also doesn't work

What am I doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons:

First, the proxy support of `nmap` is very limited, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120708/nmap-through-proxy . In fact, the `--proxy` option is ignored for everything except actual TCP connections.

And second, the SSH server implementations of many switches are quite rudimentary, offering nothing more than a serial console connection. Features like port forwarding, file transfer, remote command execution or public key authentication are missing with annoying regularity even in products from renowned manufacturers. You didn't mention the manufacturer and model of your switch, but more likely than not, it simply doesn't support the functionality necessary for using it as a proxy.

Comment: Thank you. The switches are running OpenWrt 19.07.7 with Dropbear, altough I've also installed OpenSSH at no avail.
In fact, SSH with Dropbear is doing a good job, except for this. It forwards ports, does SCP, authenticates with rsa key.
Can you comment proxychains, which also doesn't work, please?

Comment: You didn't give sufficient info on your test results with `proxychains` for me to comment.

Comment: Sorry for that. The result was essentially the same.

Comment: But I had success scanning the target network with:
$ sudo proxychains4 nmap -sT -Pn -n -v3 -d9 192.168.1.0/24
But this doesn't suit my purposes.
Anyway, I gave up this path. I'm now trying to find room in the switch memory to install nmap there and stopping this waste of time. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for letting me know.